# React.Js - Typescript how to pass an array of Objects as props?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-props, react-typescript

everyone.

So I am learning TypeScript with React.Js and I have come to a problem.

I have a "page" that has an array of objects that have further information about each user

```
const USERS = [
        {name: 'Nicole', id: 1, placeCount: 10, places: 'place 1', image: 'image source'},
        {name: 'Sarah', id: 2, placeCount: 20, places: 'place 3', image: 'asdasd'}
    ];
```

Now, I have a User page that renders list of all users, and this list is a component that is made out of UsersListItem component, now this component renders all data from each object inside the USERS array. I know how to pass one object from USERS array, but I want to send whole array with all objects

So question is how can I pass the USERS array into UsersList ?

This is my structure

This is my /users page

```
import UsersList from '../components/UsersList';


function User() {
    const USERS = [
        {name: 'Nicole', id: 1, placeCount: 10, places: 'place 1', image: 'image source'},
        {name: 'Sarah', id: 2, placeCount: 20, places: 'place 3', image: 'asdasd'}
    ];


    return (
  
        <UsersList  
            user={USERS[0].name} 
            id={USERS[0].id} 
            image={USERS[0].image} 
            placeName={USERS[0].places} 
            placeCount={USERS[0].placeCount}/>
     
      )
}

export default User
```

This is my UsersList component

```
import UsersListProps from './props/props_UserItem';
import UserIListtem from './UserIListtem';



const UsersList = ( props : UsersListProps) =>{

    const {user, id, image, placeCount, placeName} = props

    if(props === null){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>No users found</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return(
        <ul>
            {
                <UserIListtem 
                    user={user} 
                    id={id} 
                    image={image} 
                    placeName={placeName} 
                    placeCount={placeCount}/> 
            }
        </ul>
    );
  
}
```

and this is my UsersListItem component

```
import UsersListProps from './props/props_UserItem';

const UserIListtem = (props: UsersListProps) => {
    const {user, id, image, placeCount, placeName} = props;
  return (
    <li>
    <div>

        <div>
            <img src={image} alt={placeName}/>
        </div>
        <div>{id}
            <h2>{user}</h2>
            <h3>{placeCount}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</li>
  )
}

export default UserIListtem
```

And this is my UsersListProps props that I had put into seperate file called props_UserItem.tsx

```
interface UsersListProps {
    user: string,
    id: number,
    image: string,
    placeCount: number,
    placeName: string

}

export default UsersListProps
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply return this in the `User` component:

```
return (
 <UsersList users={USERS} />
)
```

Then the `UsersList` component will become:

```
const UsersList = ( { users } : UsersListProps) => {
 if(!users?.length){
   return(
     <div>
       <h1>No users found</h1>
     </div>
   );
 }
 return(
  <ul>
   {users.map(({ id, name, image, places, placeCount }) => (
     <UserIListtem
      key={id} 
      name={name} 
      id={id} 
      image={image} 
      places={places} 
      placeCount={placeCount}/> 
   ))}
  </ul>
 );
}
```

And the `UserIListtem` component:

```
const UserIListtem = ({ name: user, id, image, placeCount, places: placeName }: User) => {
 return (
  <li>
   <div>
    <div>
     <img src={image} alt={placeName}/>
    </div>
    <div>{id}
     <h2>{user}</h2>
     <h3>{placeCount}</h3>
     </div>
   </div>
  </li>
 )
}
```

Remember to also change the `UsersListProps` interface to:

```
export interface UsersListProps {
 users: User[];
}

export interface User {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 image: string;
 placeCount: number;
 places: string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing such a detailed answer! This helped me tremendously. I had to change the syntax for passing users into the UserList component. Once I changed that one small part, everything worked for me.

I changed it to this:
const UsersList: React.FC< UsersListProps > = ({ users }) => {

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace props with users: Array and then send the whole array and load the data from there in your UserIListtem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).